# Element-ui colspan in the summary raw

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Element-ui has colspan function and shows summary function, but colspan seems like doesn't work in the summary row.

In my work, I should span the summary row.

For example, I have three types of seminars and three online meeting room, and every seminar has 3 times in a month. The summary row will count every type of seminar's people coming. An example is like the following picture.

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoiEU.png)

Is it possible to make this by Element-ui? In the real case, meeting rooms may be over 50 and the summary row should fixed at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:

> Use the `span-method` attribute to configure `rowspan` and `colspan`. It accepts a method, and passes an object to that method including current row `row`, current column `column`, current row index `rowIndex` and current column index `columnIndex`. The method should return an array of two numbers, the first number being `rowspan` and second `colspan`. It can also return an object with `rowspan` and `colspan` props.

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [{
          name: 'room A',
          count11: 12,
          count12: 22,
          count13: 10,
          count21: 20,
          count22: 10,
          count23: 10,
          count31: 10,
          count32: 20,
          count33: 10
        }, {
          name: 'room B',
          count11: 12,
          count12: 22,
          count13: 10,
          count21: 20,
          count22: 10,
          count23: 10,
          count31: 10,
          count32: 20,
          count33: 10
        }, {
          name: 'room C',
          count11: 12,
          count12: 22,
          count13: 10,
          count21: 20,
          count22: 10,
          count23: 10,
          count31: 10,
          count32: 20,
          count33: 10
        },
        {
          name: 'Summary',
          count11: 1,
          count12: 2,
          count13: 3,
          count21: 4,
          count22: 5,
          count23: 6,
          count31: 7,
          count32: 8,
          count33: 9
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    arraySpanMethod({
      row,
      column,
      rowIndex,
      columnIndex
    }) {
      if (rowIndex === this.tableData.length - 1) {
        if (columnIndex !== 0) {
          // You can calculate the sum of the three columns here
          row[`count1${columnIndex}`] = 666
          return [1, 3];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <el-table :data="tableData" border :span-method="arraySpanMethod" style="width: 100%" align="center">
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="B seminar" align="center">
        <el-table-column prop="count11" label="2019/11/1" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count12" label="2019/11/8" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count13" label="2019/11/15" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="P seminar" align="center">
        <el-table-column prop="count21" label="2019/11/3" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count22" label="2019/11/10" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count23" label="2019/11/17" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="C seminar" align="center">
        <el-table-column prop="count31" label="2019/11/5" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count32" label="2019/11/12" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="count33" label="2019/11/19" align="center">
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, Element-UI doesn't provide merge columns when use `:show-summary="true"`. However, you can achieve your needs in another way.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This answer is almost finished my work, at the last step, I should fix the summary row. In the real case, meeting rooms will maybe over 50. So I think to fix height but element-ui's "fixed" attribute does not work on rows.

Actually, it will be mix "span-method" and fixed the last row seems like ":show -summary"

Comment: @J.SLee You can try to use the `row-class-name` or `row-style` property to set the style of the last row (summary row).

Comment: Thank you for answer again. I try to use 'row-class-name' and set position: fixed. Finally, the last row is fixed and computable, but the summary row lost element-ui’s css, and then it can't sync scroll with horizontal scrollbar. it seems like a difficult job. Do you know how to get el-table css and horizontal scrollbar' value?